# convert date month year time to date format pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a file with timestamp column. When I try to read the file with a schema designed by myself it is populating the datetime column with null.

Source file has data as below

```
created_date
31-AUG-2016 02:48:38
31-AUG-2016 10:37:59
31-AUG-2016 23:37:51
```

where I am using the below code snippet

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
Raw_Schema = StructType([StructField("created_date",DateType(),True)])

DF = spark.read.csv("csv").option("header","true").schema(Raw_schema).load("\path")
DF.display()

created_date
null
null
null
```

in the above DF.display() is showing the result as null for all the inputs. However my expected output is as below:

```
Created_Date
31-08-2016 
31-08-2016 
31-08-2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the date format because the format in the csv file is non-standard.

```
df = (spark.read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header","true")
    .option("dateFormat", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    .schema(Raw_schema)
    .load("filepath")
)

df.show()
+------------+
|created_date|
+------------+
|  2016-08-31|
|  2016-08-31|
|  2016-08-31|
+------------+
```

Comment: sorry to say the challenge is still occurring

Comment: @batman_special could you clarify please? what problems are you still encountering?

Comment: df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("dateFormat", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").schema(Raw_Schema)\
           .load(ROS_Raw_Store))
after using the above snippet, i could still see the date appearing as the same as 
31-AUG-2016 02:48:38
31-AUG-2016 10:37:59
31-AUG-2016 23:37:51

Comment: Don't put `.createOrReplaceTempView` at the end. Otherwise you're assigning None to df.

Comment: i tried both the ways. i am still facing the same challenge

Comment: could you copy and paste the code you used into your question?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.types import *
Raw_Schema = StructType([StructField("created_date",DateType(),True)])
DF = (spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("dateFormat", "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").schema(Raw_Schema)\
           .load(ROS_Raw_Store))  that is the code i am using

Comment: when you do `df.show()`, what do you get?

Comment: df.show() gives me the below results 
31-AUG-2016 02:48:38
31-AUG-2016 10:37:59
31-AUG-2016 23:37:51

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230888/discussion-between-mck-and-batman-special).